# Spring webflow Internationalization

Tags: spring-webflow

Recently, I'm working on the spring Internationalization. Currently, the project is built with spring webflow.

I go through lots of material about spring Internationalization, and try some many different configuration. It's still not working.

the xml file is here:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="sitelocale" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
      <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
          <property name="defaultLocale" value="cn" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
          <property name="basename" value="classpath:test"/>
      </bean>
```

When I Change the defaultLocale, I can see the characters change, which I think maybe my interceptors not working. When I manually change the url with ?sitelocale=en or other locale, it doesn't work.

I have stuck in this for the whole week, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.I change localeResolver from SessionLocaleREsolver to CookieLocaleResolver, and finally it works.

I think because I just initialize my session once, and it will store the Locale one time. This is just a guess, for more detail, I will check again.

Comment: how you are setting url for refresh pages? @zzyclark